# YouTube video upload showing "Required parameter: part" error for some users

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to find out why some of our users are getting the error `"Required parameter: part"` when trying to upload a video into YouTube using YouTube API v3. Below you can see the code that we use for uploading videos. The method params are valid strings that aren't short or too long.

```
int shareYoutube(@NonNull Uri mediaUri, String mime, String mediaTitle, String postMessage, String accountName)
{
    int error = ERR_NO_ERROR;

    try {
        // Developer tags not supported yet
        //https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5012

        // Authorize the request.
        GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_UPLOAD));
        credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);

        // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
        YouTube.Builder builder = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential);
        builder.setApplicationName("TEST APP");
        YouTube youtube = builder.build();

        // Add extra information to the video before uploading.
        Video video = new Video();

        // set privacy
        VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
        status.setPrivacyStatus("public");
        video.setStatus(status);

        // Most of the video's metadata is set on the VideoSnippet object.
        VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        snippet.setTitle(mediaTitle);
        snippet.setDescription(postMessage);

        // Film & Animation https://gist.github.com/dgp/1b24bf2961521bd75d6c
        snippet.setCategoryId("1");

        // Set the keyword tags that you want to associate with the video.
        List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
        tags.add("animation");
        tags.add("cartoon");
        tags.add("2d animation");
        tags.add("drawing");
        snippet.setTags(tags);

        // Add the completed snippet object to the video resource.
        video.setSnippet(snippet);

        String fileFormat = "video/*";
        InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(fileFormat, getContentResolver().openInputStream(mediaUri));

        // Insert the video. The command sends three arguments. The first
        // specifies which information the API request is setting and which
        // information the API response should return. The second argument
        // is the video resource that contains metadata about the new video.
        // The third argument is the actual video content.
        YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youtube.videos().insert("snippet,statistics,status", video, mediaContent);

        // Insert to a channel
        //videoInsert.setOnBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel();

        // Set the upload type and add an event listener.
        MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();

        // Indicate whether direct media upload is enabled. A value of
        // "True" indicates that direct media upload is enabled and that
        // the entire media content will be uploaded in a single request.
        // A value of "False," which is the default, indicates that the
        // request will use the resumable media upload protocol, which
        // supports the ability to resume an upload operation after a
        // network interruption or other transmission failure, saving
        // time and bandwidth in the event of network failures.
        uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

        YouTubeCallbackListener callback = new YouTubeCallbackListener();
        uploader.setProgressListener(callback);

        // Call the API and upload the video.
        Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();

        synchronized (callback) {
            if (!callback.hasCallbackResult()) {
                try {
                    callback.wait();
                    error = callback.error;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    error = ERR_POST_CANCELED;
                }
            } else {
                error = callback.error;
            }
        }

        if (ERR_NO_ERROR == error && null != returnedVideo)
        {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+returnedVideo.getId()));

            mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        }

    }
    catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException userRecoverableException)
    {
        error = ERR_UNABLE_TO_AUTH_ACCOUNT;
        try {
            GoogleAuthUtil.getTokenWithNotification(
                    getApplicationContext(), accountName, "oauth2:" + YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_UPLOAD, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
        }
    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
        error = ERR_POST_ERROR;
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        error = ERR_POST_ERROR;
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        error = ERR_POST_ERROR;
        Crashlytics.logException(t);
    }

    return error;
}
```

***Error:***

```
400 Bad Request { "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "reason" : "required", "message" : "Required parameter: part", "locationType" : "parameter", "location" : "part" } ], "code" : 400, "message" : "Required parameter: part" }
```

Any thoughts on what could be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was our proguard script. All we had to do was include the following line to it.

```
-keep class com.google.api.** { *; }
```

Comment: why use this? it looks like from youtoube servers error.

Comment: in my case me not use proguard but the same error when use youtube search api.